# meteor npm not working

Tags: meteor, npm

I recently upgraded to Meteor 1.3.1 and I'm trying to install npm modules via the `meteor npm install --save package` command. I get an error that says `'C:\Users\Default' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I tried adding the paths of Meteor's npm tool to `System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Path` but I still get the same error.

Is this a Meteor version bug or is there something I can do about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a problem with Meteor's `npm.cmd` when it comes to handling username's with whitespaces. To fix this, just change the script in `npm.cmd` to `@"%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\..\lib\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*`. The file can be found at `C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/<meteor-version>/mt-os.windows.x86_32/dev_bundle/bin`.

Fix from here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/6664

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to change `npm.cmd` but it does not work still... Could you please update your answer with your code in `npm.cmd`? Thanks!

Comment: @user1665355 it's already in my answer. My `npm.cmd` file looks like this:

`@"%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\..\lib\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*`